# Identification - hornet

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It has around 3cm. Does it look like a European or Asian Hornet?
The place where I found it is Central Europe/Romania but, after the wikipedia picture for Asian Hornet's head .. it looks exactly the same.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

European hornet (*Vespa crabro*). In the Asian hornet, the black body bands are much wider and more uniform. For the European hornet, as in your specimen, the bands are thinner and appear as thin lines connecting triangular black dots. See this image for comparison:
https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/980933/view/asian-and-european-hornets-illustration